# topics are not displaying in firebase console

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-console

I have added below code to subscribe topics in Firebase:

```
Messaging.messaging().subscribe(toTopic: "topics/news")
```

I have waited for more than 24 hours. it is still not available in firebase console.

Comment: Could you [try sending a simple downstream message](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/firebase-cloud-messaging/8242/firebase-cloud-messaging#t=20170622051019827076) towards that topic and see if the subscribed devices are able to receive the message? Just want to make sure that the device(s) are subscribed accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not include the `topic/` in the topic name.

try

```
Messaging.messaging().subscribe(toTopic: "topics/news")
```

see the example here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasemessaging/api/reference/Classes/FIRMessaging#/c:objc(cs)FIRMessaging(im)subscribeToTopic: